# как размножить?

Tags: php

Есть строка `Один Два Три ... n`

Надо получить на выходе: (в общем все возможные сочетания `за исключением ОдинОдин, ДваДва, ТриТри, ОдинОдинОдин, ДваДваДва,ТриТриТри`):

```
Один
Два
Три
ОдинДва
ОдинТри
ДваОдин
ДваТри
ТриОдин
ТриДва
ОдинДваТри
ОдинТриДва
ДваОдинТри
ДваТриОдин
ТриОдинДва
ТриДваОдин
```

Код

```
$str = "один два три";
$split_str = explode(' ', $str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($split_str);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: а `113` например?

Comment: @teran Похоже на "модифицированый" факториал. Типово делается или рекурсией или циклами. Или "комбинаторная задача на неповторяющиеся сочетания"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [];
$array[1] = $main_array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$size = count($array[1]);

$arr_name = 1;
for ($count = 2; $count <= $size; $count++) {

    $this_size = count($array[$arr_name]);
    $arr_name++;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this_size; $i++) {
        $gg = $array[($arr_name-1)][$i];
        for ($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++) {
            if($gg !== $array[1][$x]) {
                $array[$arr_name][] = $gg . $array[1][$x];
            }

        }

    }
    if (!empty($main_array)) {
        $main_array = array_merge($main_array, $array[$arr_name]);
    }
    if ($arr_name > 2)
        unset($array[($arr_name-1)]);
}
unset($array[$arr_name]);
print_r($main_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

В PHP не силен, но можно использовать регулярку. Что-то типа:

```
$str = "один два три";
$split_str = explode(' ', $str);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($split_str as $value)
{ 
 if (preg_match('^([А-Я][а-я]+)\1+$', $value, $match)) 
 {
  print_r($value);
 }
} 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Тут проблемы две. Одна получить массив. Втрорая убрать дубли. Возможно второе вам удалось.

Comment: $split_str = explode(' ', $str) - разве не получение массива?

Comment: А нужен массив с сочетаниями. это больше чем просто массив. это типа массив "умножить" на массив. Типа 3 в 3-тьей степени (27) +/- довески. Комбинаторика - нудная.

Comment: А если точнее тут 3^1 + 3^2 + 3^3 - дубли.

Comment: Все-равно не понял задачу. Помог чем мог